# Can CNS neurons be stimulated with focused audio?

Tags: brain-computer-interface, stimulation

I know that neurons can be stimulated mechanically (like in the 'funny bone') and I'm wondering if neurons in the brain could be stimulated similarly, for example via focused ultrasound.